# Is there a way of passing props to class component?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a beginner in React.
I still quite don't understand how to pass props to a class component like we do in a function.
Example of a function:

```
const SurveyFormReview = ({ onCancel, formValues, submitSurvey, history }) => {
    return (
        ...
        <button
            onClick={() => submitSurvey(formValues, history)}
            className="green btn-flat right white-text"
        >
        ...
    );
};
```

Example of a class Component:

```
class ImageUpload extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            // I want to use props in here
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Each prop passed to a class-based component can be accessed on `this.props` object. Example: `this.props.submitSurvey`

Comment: From the docs: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html#passing-data-through-props

Comment: This is covered in any React docs/tutorials that use class components. I’d recommend finding a few, and bookmarking the React documentation—it will be much faster than waiting for answers on SO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use whatever attributes you want when using the ImageUpload component:

`<ImageUpload propA="someValue" propB={someVariable}/>`

From the ImageUpload component, just call the `props` property:

```
someFunction = () => {
    var propAValue = this.props.propA;
    var propBValue = this.props.propB;
}
```

That's it!

Answer (score 2):

For example

```
<ImageUpload propExample="property" />
```

Inside ImageUpload component you can access it by writing:

```
this.props.propExample
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass any value as a `props` in `Class` and `functional` components in react. Read more about [props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html)

```js
class Welcome extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return <h1>Hello, {this.props.name}</h1>;
    }
};

ReactDOM.render(
    <Welcome name="Sara" />,
    document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
    <div id="root"></div>
```